# $I,J,P\lhd R$ where P is a prime ideal and $IJ \subset P$ (therefore $I \cap J \subset P$). Show that either I or J is contained in P.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$I,J,P\lhd R$ where P is a prime ideal and $IJ \subset P$ (therefore $I \cap J \subset P$). Show that either I or J is contained in P.

I've been having a lot of trouble with this one. I've been going in cicles on my paper for what seems like forever and haven't made much progress. I was wondering if someone could lend me a new perspective?

So far i've been saying, okay, so $ij \in P$ $\forall i,j \in I,J$.

How do i use this to show that either all of $I$ or $J$ is in $P$? Something like, well $ij=i'$ for some $i' \in I$ since I is an ideal, or something.

New perspective greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $I\nsubseteq P$, say $i\in I\setminus P$. Let $j\in J$. Since $ij\in P$ and $P$ is prime, either $i\in P$ or $j\in P$. But $i\notin P$, hence $j\in P$.

$j\in J$ was arbitraty, so $J\subseteq P$.